# How to make scheduler which will run process only at working days?

Tags: etl, scheduler, informatica

I'm working with Informatica(ETL). I want that scheduler run processes only at working days (it's not always from Monday till Friday).

For example, we have not working days from 31-DEC-2020 till 10-JAN-2021. Or 20-FEB-2021 is working day but 22-FEB-2021 AND 23-FEB-2021 are holidays.

I can generate file with not working days or only working days. Can informatica scheduler read this file(or smt else) to run processes only at working days? Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Now I have on Oracle db table with working and not working days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest would be

1. create a session which will read form work-day file/table and compare with sysdate. And produce 1 row if match found else 0.
2. Then other sessions after first one - if previous row output is =1 then proceed else dont do anything.
   [image]

So basically first session will ensure if its a workday, session will proceed else it will stop.